# How to write 64 bit value as DWORD to Windows registry

Tags: c#, registry

I'm trying to write 64 bit value as a DWORD to Windows registry. I'm trying to do this, because that's what [UnityEngine.PlayerPrefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) does and I'm trying to edit those values. Funnily enough, PlayerPrefs only supports floats, but still for some reason writes them as doubles to the registry.

```
using (RegistryKey rk = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("some\\valid\\path", true))
{
    rk.SetValue("VALUE", double.MaxValue, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
}
```

Results in this error:

> System.ArgumentException: 'The type of the value object did not match the specified RegistryValueKind or the object could not be properly converted.'

What would be the easiest way to do this in C#?

Comment: Shouldn't you store `UInt32`'s as `DWORD`s?

Comment: Actually [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey.setvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2#Microsoft_Win32_RegistryKey_SetValue_System_String_System_Object_Microsoft_Win32_RegistryValueKind) claims any value lower than `Int32.MaxValue` should do.

Comment: Of course it does, but as I said, I need to write a 64bit value.

Comment: Then you should use `QWORD`.

Comment: No. The question is how to write 64 bit value as a DWORD. It'll be invalid DWORD, but it does not matter.

Comment: A DWORD value can hold 4 bytes, so by definition you cannot store 64 bits/8 bytes of data in it, so I'm not sure how you hope to achieve this.

Comment: @Iridium AFAIK, DWORD just means the value is supposed to be 4 bytes, the value can be anything though. As I also said in the question, Unity does store 8 bytes in a DWORD and that's why I need to do the same.

Comment: You learn something new every day...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way to do it:

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
static extern uint RegSetValueEx(
    UIntPtr hKey,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string lpValueName,
    int Reserved,
    RegistryValueKind dwType,
    IntPtr lpData,
    int cbData);

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern uint RegOpenKeyEx(
    IntPtr hKey,
    string subKey,
    int ulOptions,
    int samDesired,
    out UIntPtr hkResult);

[DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
public static extern int RegCloseKey(UIntPtr hKey);

static public readonly IntPtr HKEY_CURRENT_USER = new IntPtr(-2147483647);

public bool SetNamedValue(string path, string valName, double value)
{
    UIntPtr hKey = UIntPtr.Zero;
    try
    {
        if (RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, path, 0, 0x20006, out hKey) != 0)
            return false;

        int size = 8;
        IntPtr pData = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
        Marshal.WriteInt64(pData, BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(value));
        if (RegSetValueEx(hKey, valName, 0, RegistryValueKind.DWord, pData, size) != 0)
            return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (hKey != UIntPtr.Zero)
            RegCloseKey(hKey);
    }
    return true;
}
```